# Determine current download speed using ssh on Openelec

Tags: ssh, openelec

I am running Openelec v5.0.8 on a Raspberry Pi model B. I would like to determine the download speed when streaming videos from various addons. I have searched and cannot find an SSH command to do so.

I want an ssh command that returns the current download speed (not maximum download speed)?

Answer (score 1):

Use wget, and download something. You'll see different rates as it downloads, and get a time, an a file-size from which you can calculate average.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-test-your-internet-speed-with-a-terminal-command-1364123567

Comment: I want a command where the speed is returned after the command is entered.

Comment: so write one. you could use awk, on the wget output. but your download rates vary, and bandwidth is depended on client and server availability. Alternatively, you could update your question with what software, you are using to do the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Try the tool called iptraf. You can get it with `sudo apt-get install iptraf` and then run it with `sudo iptraf`. The first menu option will allow you to monitor the speed of any tcpip download from any program. Since iptraf is program agnostic it can be started after the download has begun.